# Regex to match number after a defined text

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have the following text to apply regex on, where I want to replace all occurences of ,N, to be replaced by ""

1,N,1,XROW30_!@#@!#_1231_asdsad

I was able to test this regex (,N,[\d]) in http://regexr.com/ . The expression seems to correctly match the text.

However when I use it on my program, the regex does not work

```
val regN = """(,N,[\d])"""

...
.map (row => row.replace(regN, ""))
```

The end result im looking for is this
1,XROW30_!@#@!#_1231_asdsad

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.replace` this method will not replace by regex: [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-)

you should use `String.replaceFirst` or `String.replaceAll`:[String.replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks @chengpohi. This was indeed the issue.